# Find the number of natural solutions to an equation with limitations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I'm trying to solve this issue:

> Find the number of number of natural solutions to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 13$, where 0 is also a natural number, with the following limitations:
>
> 1. When $x_i \ne i$ for every $i \in \{1,2,3\}$ .
> 2. When $i\le x_i \le i+3$ for every $i \in \{1,2,3\}$ .

For the first one, I understand that I could find all solutions and deduce the ones where ever $x_i = i$, but is there a quicker route?

And also the second route should have less solutions, correct?

Thanks!

Comment: You should include your effort to solve the problem and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, we can set $x_i=i$ for $i=1,2,3$ and count the solutions to the resulting equation.  For example, when $i=1$ we want the number of solutions to $$x_2+x_3=12$$ which is $13$.  Then we can add up the results.  Of course, solutions where $x_i=i$ for two different values of $i$ have been counted twice, so we have to subtract them.  There are obviously $3$ of these, and there are no solutions where $x_i=i$ for all three values of $i$, so that finishes it.

The second condition takes a little more work.  We can use generating functions.  I'll use the coefficient extraction operator $[\cdot]$ where $[x^n]P(x)$ mean the coefficient of $x^n$ in $P(x)$, where $P$ is a polynomial or a power series.  The desired number is
$$
[x^{13}](x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)\\
=[x^{13}]x^6(1+x+x^2+x^3)^3\\
=[x^7]\left(\frac{1-x^4}{1-x}\right)^3=[x^7](1-x^4)^3(1-x)^{-3}\\
=[x^7](1-3x^4+3x^8-x^{12})\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\binom{-3}nx^n\\
=[x^7](1-3x^4)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+2}{2}x^n\\
\binom92-3\binom52=36-30=6 
$$

**EDIT**

For a small problem like this, it's probably easier to cube $1+x+x^2+x^3$ manually (or just square it and pick out the terms that will result in terms in $x^7$ in the cube), but I wanted to show you the technique for larger problems.